# Start kdc in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, kdc

In Dockerfile, I put in the following:

```
COPY docker-files/krb5.conf /etc
RUN /usr/sbin/krb5kdc -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid;
```

Expectation is that KDC would be started when I use "docker run -it" command.

However, KDC is not running after starting docker VM.
Was my expectation correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RUN is not the same as CMD

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

or

ENTRYPOINT

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

By default a docker container executes what it has in CMD and exits, so that is "normal".

Try replacing RUN by CMD, rebuild and relaunch

See also creack answer in

[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile?rq=1)

Comment: I changed the RUN with CMD and relaunched the docker VM. krb5kdc is still not active in the VM. BTW for "docker run", I specified "-h=securecluster". Not sure whether this would play some role in what I observed.

Comment: Does this command last long or gives back a prompt immediately?

Comment: try `CMD /usr/sbin/krb5kdc -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid; sleep infinity`

Comment: Doesn't the above mean that only one process can be started in this manner ?

Comment: To answer previous question, start-docker.sh builds the docker image and runs the image. It was not immediately clear how long the kdc command in Dockerfile ran.

Comment: You can run several processes with supervisor https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/ or s6 or daemontools

Answer (score 0):

First, use CMD (takes effect on run time) instead of RUN (takes effect on build time)

Then put krb in foreground with `-n`:

```
CMD /usr/sbin/krb5kdc -n -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid
```

But if it is still not working, post the `docker logs` of that container

Comment: You said "then put krb in foreground". Does this mean that I need two CMD's for krb5kdc ? In the previous output, there was only one CMD.

Comment: Looking at /var/log/krb5kdc.log , there was no indication that the krb5kdc actually ran - the log file is empty.

Comment: When you **docker run** bash you are overriding the CMD with bash. To try what you need, do the same docker run, without the bash, and in another terminal, do `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` then `ps aux`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did see kdc running as described above. However, the *docker run* command is supposed to give developers a terminal where they can build / test native code. Currently after "krb5kdc: starting..." message the terminal is not usable. Any suggestion ?

Comment: `docker run -d` (add -d before image name). Then use docker stop/kill to stop container. Is it what you asked?

Comment: Is there any downside to starting kdc within the *docker run* command like this ? -it hbase_native /bin/bash -c "/usr/sbin/krb5kdc -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid; /bin/bash"

Comment: There is no problem. The thing is that you remain attached to the terminal. For production stuff is not the best approach. This is equivalent without bash: `-t -d hbase_native /bin/bash -c "/usr/sbin/krb5kdc -n -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid"`